# Bert Transformer "Size Error" while Machine Traslation

Tags: python-3.x, translation, huggingface-transformers

I am getting desperate as I have no clue what is the problem over here. I want to translate a list of sentences from german to english. This is my code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-de-en")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-de-en")

batch = tokenizer(
    list(data_bert[:100]),
    padding=True,
    truncation=True,
    max_length=250,
    return_tensors="pt"
)



results = model(batch)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniconda3/envs/textmallet/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in __getattr__(self, item)
    247         try:
--> 248             return self.data[item]
    249         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'size'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_26502/2652187977.py in <module>
     14 
     15 
---> 16 results = model(batch)
     17 

~/miniconda3/envs/textmallet/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/miniconda3/envs/textmallet/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/marian/modeling_marian.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, decoder_input_ids, decoder_attention_mask, head_mask, decoder_head_mask, cross_attn_head_mask, encoder_outputs, past_key_values, inputs_embeds, decoder_inputs_embeds, labels, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1274                 )
   1275 
-> 1276         outputs = self.model(
   1277             input_ids,
   1278             attention_mask=attention_mask,
```

I have no clue what could be the precise issue over here. If someone can help me out I d be really thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the problem described here (credits to
LysandreJik): https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5480, the problem appears to be the data type of a `dict` instead of `tensor`.

It might be the case that you need to change the tokenizer output from:

```
batch = tokenizer(
    list(data_bert[:100]),
    padding=True,
    truncation=True,
    max_length=250,
    return_tensors="pt"
)
```

TO:

```
batch = tokenizer(
    list(data_bert[:100]),
    padding=True,
    truncation=True,
    max_length=250,
    return_tensors="pt")["input_ids"]
```

Comment: What happens if you do : outputs= model(input_ids=input_ids, decoder_input_ids=input_ids)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Just a quick understanding question: Do you know how to interpret the output. For a week I am getting into transformers now and it is still searching and trying...

Comment: It really depends on the task you are trying to solve. As per my understanding, the actual outputs are word embeddings with context, what you do with those embeddings is up to you/task at hand etc.

Answer (score 0):

For me, passing `model(**batch)` instead of `model(batch)` helped. Also, about Timbus Calin answer: in some cases, using slice with only `input_ids` key may not be enough since tokenizer output contains other valuable items for model such as `attention_mask`, which tells model about padded elements in input sequence, etc (more details about tokenizer outputs [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__)).